# Animating a line to go around a circle

Tags: java, processing

The code below creates circles inside of circles and each circle goes around their parent circle. I'm trying to draw a line from the center of the parent circle to the center of the child circle that follows it around for each one. How would I go about doing that?
I'm also using Processing if that means anything.

```java
float x = 350.0;
float y = 350.0;
float dia = 699;
float i = 1;
float z;
float p;
float s = 500;

void setup(){
  size(700,700);
}

void draw(){
  noFill();
  stroke(255);
  strokeWeight(1);
  background(0);
  scale(1);
  DrawCircle(x, y, dia, i);
}

float DrawCircle(float x, float y, float d, float i){
  strokeWeight(1);
  ellipse(x, y, d, d);
  strokeWeight(3);
  point(x,y);
  z += 0.001;
  x += (sin(i*z/d*s)/2)*d/2;
  y += (cos(i*z/d*s)/2)*d/2;

  if(d > 0.1){
    DrawCircle(x, y, d/2, i * -1); 
  }
  return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `DrawCircle` has to return the center point of the circle. Use [`PVector`](https://processing.org/reference/PVector.html) for the return type:

```java
PVector DrawCircle(float x, float y, float d, float i) {
    // [...]

    return new PVector(x, y);
}
```

Draw a line from the current center point to the center point which is returned from the recursive call:

```java
PVector innerCpt = DrawCircle(x, y, d/2, i * -1); 
line(innerCpt.x, innerCpt.y, x, y);
```

See the example:

[image]

```java
float x = 350.0;
float y = 350.0;
float dia = 699;
float i = 1;
float z;
float p;
float s = 500;

void setup(){
    size(700,700);
}

void draw(){
    noFill();
    stroke(255);
    strokeWeight(1);
    background(0);
    scale(1);
    DrawCircle(x, y, dia, i);
}

PVector DrawCircle(float x, float y, float d, float i){
    strokeWeight(1);
    ellipse(x, y, d, d);
    strokeWeight(3);
    point(x,y);
    z += 0.001;
    x += (sin(i*z/d*s)/2)*d/2;
    y += (cos(i*z/d*s)/2)*d/2;

    if(d > 0.1){
        PVector innerCpt = DrawCircle(x, y, d/2, i * -1); 
        line(innerCpt.x, innerCpt.y, x, y);
    }
    return new PVector(x, y);
}
```